# How to perform an action on class's field using dialog created by IntelliJ Idea designer

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm curious how can I use a dialog designer that is built into IntelliJ IDEA since I find it an option with big potential but I don't really know how to use it.

Let's consider a desktop program with two classes created using designer: `MainWindow` and `MainDialog`. Let's assume that `MainWindow` class already has all fields, components etc. required for a simple form to be displayed. Then in the `MainWindow` class we have:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("This is default text");
JButton showDialog = new JButton("Show dialog");
showDialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                MainDialog dialog = new MainDialog ();
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

which makes the dialog visible. The `MainDialog` class designed by default by designer looks like this:

```
public class MainDialog extends JDialog {
private JPanel contentPane;
private JButton buttonOK;
private JButton buttonCancel;

public MainDialog() {
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    setModal(true);
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(buttonOK);

    buttonOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            onOK();
        }
    });

    buttonCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            onCancel();
        }
    });

// call onCancel() when cross is clicked
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            onCancel();
        }
    });

// call onCancel() on ESCAPE
    contentPane.registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            onCancel();
        }
    }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
}

private void onOK() {
// add your code here
    dispose();
}

private void onCancel() {
// add your code here if necessary
    dispose();
}
}
```

Now let's also assume that in the dialog class I have a text field:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
```

that I am getting a text to be displayed by label in the `MainWindow` class from.

Since I have an `onOK()` function created by default I'd like it to update a label in `MainWindow` class with text typed in text field in `MainDialog` class.

The problem is: how can I perform an action on another class's field using this pattern **without** writing in `MainDialog` a line `MainWindow window = new MainWindow` or making `label` `static`? Is it possible? I know that this can be done much simpler but this is also an easy example and I'd like to perform much more complex operations using this structure.

Comment: Your question title is inflammatory and a poor fit for the stack overflow format, I recommend changing the title to actually reflect your question in order to attract more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

First option: since the dialog is modal, the code opening the modal in the main window will be blocked until the dialog is closed. So you could just do something like this in the modal:

```
public String getEnteredText() {
    return textField.getText();
}
```

and in the main window:

```
dialog.setVisible(true);
myLabel.setText(dialog.getEnteredText());
```

Or (but I would use the first option), you can pass the main window, or any other callback, to the dialog. For example:

```
MainDialog dialog = new MainDialog(this);
```

And in the dialog:

```
private void onOK() {
    mainWindow.setLabelText(textField.getText());
    dispose();
}
```

My recommendation is to avoid UI designers. Especially if you're not able yet to write the code that they generate by yourself, and you don't have a deep understanding of how Swing works.

Comment: I actually already tried your first option but it's not a good way. In this option a label is updated whenever I close the dialog no matter whether I pressed ok or cancel Button. Nów let's assume that I'm not updating a label but asking whether delete a user from a database - it would be stupid to delete him despite pressed Button. Btw I AM able to write designers code by my own, but using it speeds up my work like 3x, so if I have a tool I'd like to know how can I use IT

Comment: Then set a boolean variable `okPressed` to true before closing the dialog when OK is pressed, and use `if (dialog.isOkPressed()) {myLabel.setText(dialog.getEnteredText());}`. As simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it in a minute